# Имена собственные.

Tags: лингвистика

Adriano Celentano Челентано но Toto Cutugno Кутуньо . Один язык . Одна буква C . А какие разные судьбы.

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'C' в итальянском читается как "ч" перед 'e' и 'i' (перед остальными гласными - "к"), а в русский язык транскрипция имён с итальянского делается по произношению (поэтому "Челентано" и "Кутуньо"). Если требуется с этими гласными образовать звук "к", то после 'c' добавляется 'h'. Аналогично с 'g' ("дж" или "г") - отсюда, напр. правильная транскрипция "ЛамборГини".